# I want to include .env information in samconfig.toml

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to include the AWS key as an environment variable in samconfig.toml, but do not want to pass the key directly to the code.
So I thought I would place the .env and pass its value to samconfig.toml.
However, I am having trouble getting that method to work.
Is it possible to include the value in samconfig.toml without writing the value directly?

Here is my configuration file.
samconfig.toml

```
# More information about the configuration file can be found here:
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html
version = 0.1

[dev]
[dev.deploy]
[dev.deploy.parameters]
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
confirm_changeset = false
s3_bucket = "develop"
resolve_s3 = false
profile = "dev"
parameter_overrides = """
    Env=dev \
    AccessKeyId=${AccessKeyId} \
    SecretAccessKey=${SecretAccessKey}\
"""
```

.env

```
AccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxx
SecretAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Use AWS secret manager

Comment: I know how to use AWS secret manager.
Other than that, I would like to know how to supplement it with a file that can hold environment variables such as .env.
Thanks.